# Arbitrary key or legend with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of 3d data, where the third dimension is represented by changing colour of the line on a 2d plot, as in this example: [Multicolored line example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)

Is there a way to make a key or legend to display the meaning of each colour? Due to the way this example works, I don't see how it can be achieved, and can't see anything online about creating an arbitrary key. As I know the colours and what they mean, I was hoping I could just use this information to make a key somehow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How many colors are there? For a few making a custom legend as ali_m shows would work. For many (near continuous) a colorbar might be more appropriate.

Comment: There's only 5, so a custom legend is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could just 'cheat' by drawing a set of dummy lines representing each of the colours in your real multicoloured line:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
labels = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
dummies = [ax.plot([], [], ls='-', c=c)[0] for c in colors]        
ax.legend(dummies, labels)
```

I'm not sure if there's a neater way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps or is what you were thinking about, but you can also use a colorbar and, if the lines you plot are not mappable, create a dummy colorbar like this

```
Z = [[0,0],[0,0]]
levels = range(0,60)    #or whatever you need here
CS3 = contourf(Z, levels, **kwargs)
clf()                   #deletes the dummy plot
cb = colorbar(CS3)
cb.set_label("label")
```